# Laravel 5 Login without Database and giving reponse JWT

Tags: laravel, jwt

Need Help, How to get JWT Token after login without Database I try to use tymondesigns/jwt-auth but it give me "Call to a member function send() on null" error.

Here's my Code at AuthController (construct and  login Function)

```
 public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);
}


public function login()
{
    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

    if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }

    return $this->respondWithToken($token);
}
```

I'm using custom Middleware :

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Session;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class CustomMiddleware
{
protected $loginPath = 'login';

public function handle($request, Closure $next) 
{
    if (!empty(session('login')))
    {
        $logged_in = $request->session()->put('logged_in');

        if (!$logged_in) 
        {
            return redirect()->guest('login')->with('flag','1');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And Here's for my routes at api.php

```
 Route::group([

'middleware' => 'custom',
'prefix' => 'auth'

 ], function ($router) {

Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
Route::post('me', 'AuthController@me');

});
```

in the kernel.php i put :

```
'custom' => \App\Http\Middleware\CustomMiddleware::class,
```

Answer (score 1):

After installing JWT as per the documentation you should use

```
$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)
```

instead of `$token = auth()->attempt($credentials)`